# How to calculate the radial cross section of a torus depending on a certain angle?

Tags: geometry, area

Imagine a torus, I cutted in half:

[image]

It is quite easy to calculate the **red** area:

$$A_1(\alpha=0) = \pi ( R+r)^2 - \pi R^2$$

as well as the **green** area:

$$A_1(\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}) = 2\pi R \cdot r$$

But how could one calculate the area at certain angle $\alpha$ in the range $[0,\pi]$?

I came up with something like

$$ A(\alpha) = 2\pi R r + \pi r^2 \cdot \cos(\alpha)$$

which would be true for $\alpha = 0,~ \pi/2,~ \pi$ - but how can I be sure that it is correct for all the other $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cross section is equivalent to the [lateral surface area of a truncated cone](http://www.mathwords.com/f/frustum.htm) with radii $r_1,r_2$ and slant height $s$:

$$A(r_1,r_2,s) = \pi(r_1+r_2)s.$$

Here, the slant height is $r$.  The height of the truncated cone is $r \sin \alpha$, so if one radius is $R$, the other is $R - r \cos \alpha$.

This gives your cross-sectional area:

$$A(R,r,\alpha) = \pi(2R - r \cos \alpha)r.$$

This is valid for all $\alpha$ between $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: I would never have found this analogy, thanks!